# How to remove everything in a string after first occurence of a substring in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have a string

`string date = "2017-04-06 05:00:00 a.m. +8:30a.m";`

i need to trim the above string after first occurence of a.m , my output should be

`2017-04-06 05:00:00 a.m.`

How to achieve this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here this should help:

```
string date = "2017-04-06 05:00:00 a.m. +8:30a.m";
var s = date.Substring(0, date.IndexOf("a.m") + "a.m".Length);
```

Comment: the output should be 2017-04-06 05:00:00 a.m , but your answer is returning me the index i.e, 20

Comment: @Meena- i am not sure what you mean its working: http://ideone.com/vkYw3s

Comment: @Meena: His suggestion works fine, take a [Look here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MHWeTX)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Substring` if you can ensure that the format will remain the same for all records. Use the below;

`date.Substring(0, 22));`

Where 0 is the startIndex and 22 is the length of the string you need.

Else, if the length is not fixed, you can proceed with the `Split` function;

`Dim result As String() = input.Split(New String() {"a.m"}, StringSplitOptions.None);`

However, the result is a in an array,

`date = result(0);`

Comment: length of the string is not fixed, please give me answer which supports for any length

Comment: You still need to append the pattern "a.m." to the final result

Answer (score 0):

str.substring(0, str.indexOf("a.m."));

or

String.split, with limit 1

str.split("a.m.", 1)[0];

Comment: In first solution one you need to append `a.m.`  and second one would fail, if the `a.m.` is not present as array would be empty

Answer (score 0):

Maybe thinking too much ahead, but probably your next question will be: How can I split a string on both `a.m.` AND `p.m.`?

Among all solutions, let me be the guy telling you to use regular expressions (there is always one):

```
string date = "2017-04-06 05:00:00 a.m. +8:30a.m";
var s = Regex.Match(date, @"(.+[ap]\.m\.)").Groups[1];
```

This will not only get you dates with a.m. but also with p.m. and when the format changes you only have to change the pattern and not the inner workings of a Substring method. 
<s>Probably you want to refactor this out into `Groups` but that is up to you.</s>

Comment: This will not providing the correct result, I tried the following:

`string date = "2017-04-06 05:00:00 a.m. +8:30a.m.";`
`string pattern = @".+[a]\.m\."; ` 
`Regex.Match(date,pattern).ToString()`

**Result**
`2017-04-06 05:00:00 a.m. +8:30a.m.`

Comment: Also I have already provided a Regex solution, which also splits data using pattern, but your point related to p.m. is good

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Oh, yeah, it is due to the last dot in the input data, I'll correct that. That is why you want Matches and Groups, gives more control. Like you, I like to use regex over string methods, because it separates the pattern from implementation.